# Using Craft for publishing an online magazine

Tags: entry, structure

I was wondering if Craft is suitable for publishing online magazines. I was thinking about using a new structure for every issue/release. And entries for the actual content of an issue.

Is this the way to go? And does it affect Craft's performance?

Thnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn’t recommend creating a ton of Structure sections, because the administration workflows and UI are just not suited for having lots of identical sections.

Here’s a basic model of how you could organize this in Craft:

- Create two [Sections](https://craftcms.com/docs/sections-and-entries) called **Issues** and **Articles**
- Create an [Entries field](https://craftcms.com/docs/entries-fields) called **Issue Articles**, with the **Articles** section selected.
- Edit your **Issues** section’s Entry Type, and add the **Issue Articles** field to its Field Layout.

Now, each issue will be represented by an entry within your **Issues** section, and each article will be represented by an entry within your **Articles** section.

Thanks to the new Inline Element Creation feature in [Craft 2.5](https://craftcms.com/news/craft-2.5), you will easily be able to define new articles right from the Edit Entry page when creating/editing a new issue, via your **Issue Articles** field.

Comment: Great! Thnx for your help.